# How to use Expo Push Token with Laravel-Exponent-Push-Notifications?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, react-native, expo

Edit: I got the idea that We create a table called ‘exponent_push_notifiation_interests’ by migration, The question here is this is the table that will hold push key? ... I accessed created table and I found two columns key and value and if so how could I access token to use it within code snippet mentioned in the package ReadMe.

We are building an app with Expo and We are trying to enable push notifications with our backend service which is written with php (Laravel), We are working with [Laravel-Exponent-Push-Notifications](https://github.com/Alymosul/laravel-exponent-push-notifications)

The following code snippet is used to send Notification with in Laravel project:

```
<?php
namespace App\Notifications;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoChannel;
use NotificationChannels\ExpoPushNotifications\ExpoMessage;
class Notification_app extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return [ExpoChannel::class];
    }

    public function toExpoPush($notifiable)
    {
       return ExpoMessage::create()
           ->badge(1)
           ->enableSound()
           ->title("Congratulations!")
           ->body("Your {$notifiable->service} account was approved!");
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
       return [
           //
       ];
    }
}
```

Then calling the function to send notification like so `$data->notify(new Notification_app());`

On the client side the code is looks like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
    registerForPushNotificationsAsync();
    Notifications.addListener(_handleNotification);
},
[])

const registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    console.log(Constants.isDevice);
    if (Constants.isDevice) {
        const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
        let finalStatus = existingStatus;
        if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
            const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
            finalStatus = status;
        }
        console.log(finalStatus);
        if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
            alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
            return;
        }
        let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
        setExpoPushToken(token);
    } else {
        alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
    }

    if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        Notifications.createChannelAndroidAsync('default', {
            name: 'default',
            sound: true,
            priority: 'max',
            vibrate: [0, 250, 250, 250],
        });
    }
};

const _handleNotification = notification => {
    console.log(notification);
    Vibration.vibrate();
    if(notification.origin == 'selected'){
        props.navigation.navigate('MyTaskDetails');
    }
    setNotification();
};
```

Here we generate Expo push token then I know that we have to send it to backend so that each token will be related to a device which have our app installed, My question here is how to use device token (Expo Push token) in the above Laravel code to send notification to a specific device there is no parameters that refer to any token ... any help or snippet of code that might help me here is appreciated.